# Looking for a snippet to convert a string into a list of integers

Tags: python

As an example:

```
>> s = '0123456' 
>> list(s)
['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6']
```

I have come up with this:

```
>> map( lambda x:int(x), list(s) )
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Can this be improved ?

Comment: What's _wrong_ with your current solution? Does it not work? Is it too slow? Were you ridiculed by your team-mates? Seriously, sometimes you just need to let go of absolute perfection and deliver the product :-)

Comment: I have not been ridiculed yet. But perhaps I should get over my embarrassment & just check it in.

Comment: @paxdiablo: It is not wrong perse, as the only thing that should "necessarily" be changed would be the `lis(s)` since string are iterables.

Answer (score 9):

Just use a list comprehension, or if appropriate a generator expression. Simple, and a bit faster (arguably) more readable.

```
[int(x) for x in s]
```

Comment: List comprehensions are generally preferred over using map(), filter(), reduce(), etc.

Comment: you don't need to call `iter` just `[int(x) for x in s]` is enough

Comment: """List comprehensions are generally preferred over using map(), filter(), reduce(), etc""" - this is completely subjective.

Comment: @Sentinel no it's not. 99% of time comprehensions offers more readability. Also, 2to3 transforms `map(f, it)` in `list(map(f, it))` and that's ugly

Answer (score 6):

```
>>> map(int, ['1', '2'])
[1, 2]

>>> map(int, '123')
[1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: Right. I don't need the lambda

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing *really* wrong with your approach except it is not necessary to convert the string into a list since strings are iterables.

```
>>> s = '0123456' 
>>> map(lambda x:int(x), s)
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

If you prefer the list comprehension/iterator see [@zeekay's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6420273/looking-for-a-snippet-to-convert-a-string-into-a-list-of-integers/6420279#6420279) answer.

Comment: As a note, list comprehension seems to be much faster for this case in python 2.x